# Django: different project with same name but located on different directories

Tags: python, django

This is my project structure

```
prod/
    projectName/
test/
    projectName/
```

My apache settings are configured so that:
www.projectname.com points to:

```
prod/projectName/
```

and test.projectname.com points to:

```
test/projectName/
```

will this work in django?

Here are the vhost configurations for both urls

Test:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@projectname.com
    ServerName test.projectname.com
    ServerAlias test.projectname.com

    DocumentRoot /django_projects/test/projectname/

    ErrorLog /django_projects/test/projectname/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /django_projects/test/projectname/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /django_projects/test/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /django_projects/test/projectname/static/
    Alias /media /django_projects/test/projectname/media/

    <Directory /django_projects/test/projectname>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /django_projects/test/projectname/templates>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
WSGIPythonPath /django_projects/test/projectname/
```

Prod:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@projectname.com
    ServerName projectname.com
    ServerAlias projectname.com

    DocumentRoot /django_projects/prod/projectname/

    ErrorLog /django_projects/prod/projectname/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /django_projects/prod/projectname/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /django_projects/prod/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /django_projects/prod/projectname/static/
    Alias /media /django_projects/prod/projectname/media/

    <Directory /django_projects/prod/projectname>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /django_projects/prod/projectname/templates>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
WSGIPythonPath /django_projects/prod/projectname/
```

Because right now both test.projectname.com and www.projectname.com points to prod/projectName/ despite having different vhost configurations.

Thank You!

Comment: can you paste related vhost configurations?

Comment: you need to have one .wsgi files for each project.you need to configure it in /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.projectname.com for test project.use a2ensite command to enable test.projectname.com.

Comment: Can you provide .wsgi file and apache file config in sites-available

Comment: "points to" I meant, both sites are opening the same projects despite having different configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. Run both as a daemon. Also make sure you wsgi.py scripts are configured correctly.

Config for test, and then the same for prod. But they will be configured as different sites in apache:

Inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.projectname.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@projectname.com
    ServerName test.projectname.com
    ServerAlias test.projectname.com

    DocumentRoot /django_projects/test/projectname/

    ErrorLog /django_projects/test/projectname/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /django_projects/test/projectname/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess test processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIScriptAlias / /django_projects/test/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /django_projects/test/projectname/static/
    Alias /media /django_projects/test/projectname/media/

    <Directory /django_projects/test/projectname>
        WSGIProcessGroup test
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /django_projects/test/projectname/templates>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Inside /etc/apache2/sites-available/projectname.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@projectname.com
    ServerName projectname.com
    ServerAlias projectname.com

    DocumentRoot /django_projects/prod/projectname/

    ErrorLog /django_projects/prod/projectname/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /django_projects/prod/projectname/logs/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess prod processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIScriptAlias / /django_projects/prod/projectname/projectname/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /django_projects/prod/projectname/static/
    Alias /media /django_projects/prod/projectname/media/

    <Directory /django_projects/prod/projectname>
        WSGIProcessGroup prod
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /django_projects/prod/projectname/templates>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After you done:

```
$ sudo a2ensite test.projectname.com
$ sudo a2ensite projectname.com
```

Something like that :)

Comment: Thank You Alexey!
Another lesson learned by a Django noob! :)